# nargin, vargin, exist, what is the best way to implement optional arguments matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function in matlab:

```
function output = myfunc(a,b,c,d,e)
      %a and b are mandetory
      %c d and e are optional
end
```

How would I handle inputs if a user gave an optional arg for e but not for c and d?

nargin just gives the number of arguments. would exist be the best way?

Comment: A user can't provide only the fifth input. You could have them provide empty values `[]` for `c` and `d` and detect that. Otherwise, maybe consider using parameter/value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use *nargin*. It will tell you how many arguments are present. Use varargin only when you have a *variable* number of arguments, that is you have no limit in number of arguments, or you want to access the arguments in an indexing fashion. I assume this is not the case for you, so one solution might look like this.

```
function output = myfunc(a,b,c,d,e)
  %a and b are mandetory
  %c d and e are optional
  if nargin < 3 || isempty(c)
     c = <default value for c>
  end
  if nargin < 4 || isempty(d)
     d = <default value for d>
  end
  if nargin < 5 || isempty(e)
     e = <default value for e>
  end
  <now do dome calculation using a to e>
  <If a or b is accessed here, but not provded by the caller an error is generated by MATLAB>
```

If the user does not want to provide a value for c or d but provides e, he has to pass [], e.g. *func(a,b,c,[],e)*, to omit d.

Alternatively you could use

```
if nargin == 5
   <use a b c d and e>
elseif nargin == 2
   <use a and b>
else    
   error('two or five arguments required');
end
```

to check if all a arguments e are present. But this requires exactly 2 or 5 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can to define `c`, `d` and `e` as optional and then assign values based on position.  This requires empty inputs if they want `e` but not `c`.  For example:

```
function output = myfunc( a, b, varargin )

optionals = {0,0,0}; % placeholder for c d e with default values

numInputs = nargin - 2; % a and b are required
inputVar = 1;

while numInputs > 0
    if ~isempty(varargin{inputVar})
        optionals{inputVar} = varargin{inputVar};
    end
    inputVar = inputVar + 1;
    numInputs = numInputs - 1;
end

c = optionals{1};
d = optionals{2};
e = optionals{3};

output = a + b + c + d + e;
```

This will just add everything together.  There is alot of error checking that needs to happen with this.  A better approach might be `inputParser`.  This does paired inputs and checking.  See [Input Parser help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html)